# Eclipse где прописаны настройки workspace

Tags: eclipse

Структура моего проекта следующая имеется общая папка и в ней несколько maven проектов (микросервисов).
Я удалил один из проект из workspace.
Теперь я хочу его же добавить обратно (File->Open Project...), но в ответ получаю ошибку:

```
Select at least one folder to import as project.
```

Я так понимаю, проблема в том, что такая папка уже прописана где-то в настройках Eclipse, т.к. если я ее изменю ее имя, то она добавляется без ошибок.
Где в Eclipse храниться эта информация с названием проекта? Как ее удалить, чтобы можно было добавить проект не меняя его названия?

Пробовал удалять все конфигурационные файлы из проекта.

Создавал новую рабочую область и переключался в нее.

Ни чего не помогает

Comment: попробуй не open, а import

Comment: если делаю import, то у меня получается не maven проект, а просто набор папок. Я добавил описание по структуре проекта